# How to shuffle each column of pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

For example, my text file looks like

```
John Smith 19 
Alex Greelish 89
Sandra Alexandru 44
```

How can I shuffle each column? Example of expected result:

```
Sandra Greelish 44
Alex Smith 19
John Alexandru 89
```

Currently, my code looks in the following way:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test.txt', sep=" ", header=None)
print(df.sample(frac=1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with convert to numpy array for prevent index alignement:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.sample(frac=1).to_numpy())
```